# Why am I getting this error from IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc

I have created a very simple ASP.NET MVC3 application that runs just fine in the Visual Studio debugger.

However, I have tried to add this application to my local IIS installation. I added the project by right-clicking Sites and clicking "Add Web Site" (specifying the project's folder and setting port to 9000).

However, firing up Chrome and going to `http://localhost:9000` yields the following error:

[image]

It looks like some sort of permissions problem, but I have no idea what I would do to fix this.

**More details:**

- OS: Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit
- IIS: 7.0.6000.16386
- Visual Studio 2010 Express with SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this out:

http://supreethkshankar.webs.com/apps/blog/show/4959215-compiler-error-message-cs0016-could-not-write-to-output-file-access-is-denied

It looks like something is wrong with your Temp folder permissions.

Comment: Yup - that was the problem. I gave `IIS_IUSRS` full access to the temp folder and it works now.